# SharePoint 2013 *.stp import to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, import, survey, stp

I recently created a Survey in SharePoint 2013 and exportet it as a Survey-Template. Now I have a *.stp File which I try to use in a SharePoint 2010 System.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Sharepoint solutions have some limited backwards-compatibility. Which means a Sharepoint 2010 solution may work on a Sharepoint 2013 server, but not the other way around.

I suppose you have used Visual Studio to build your solution?

You will have to change all dependencies and references from your Sharepoint 2013 solution to Sharepoint 2010. This can be really a lot of work.

I think you now have 2 options:

- Make a sharepoint 2010 solution out of it and see it it runs under Sharepoint 2013
- If the point above didn't work and you really want to make it available for both sharepoint versions, I suggest you to create 2 separate Visual Studio projects.